# How do I scale my unscalable microservice?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, kubernetes, microservices

I want to deploy a microservice in my AKS with two replicas and I have a problem scaling (horizontally) my service. I explain my issue:

When a client makes an *HTTP* request to the *API*, I lock it, and I send a command through the *Azure Service Bus*, and I dont unlock it until I have the answer through another command. The problem is that if I have **two** instances of my service, the instance which is not connected to the client may receive the command, so it is no able to reply the client. So I think that the system is not scalable... Do you have any suggestion?

[image: Here I leave the system scheme]

**Thank you very much!**

Comment: How have you deployed your app on **kubernetes** ? Do you use a `Deployment` ? It seems like a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/), which *provides guarantees about the ordering and uniqueness of these Pods* might be a better choice for you.

Comment: Use a shared service like Cache , DB to update the command response so both instance can serve it. You need to log the request in DB  and then drop the message with reference on Azure Service Bus . When response arrive any of your instance can handle and update the response against the reference and update db . This way you can scale. You are using stateful approach which makes it difficult to scale.